# Probability distribution of atomic energy in a canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, equilibrium, molecular-dynamics

Imagine we have a system of atoms in the canonical (NVT) ensemble. For this system, we know that under thermal equilibrium, the probability distribution $P(E)$ of the system's total energy $E$ satisfies the Boltzmann distribution $P(E) = \exp(-E/kT)/Z$. Is it true that the probability distribution of each atom's energy $e$ in the system, $P(e)$, also satisfies the Boltzmann distribution $P(e) = \exp(-e/kT)/z$ $(z = \sum_e \exp(-e/kT))$, assuming all particles are of the same species? What if the system consists of atoms of different species?

Comment: Note that for a noninteracting system the distribution function for the whole system seperates into the product of the distribution function of the particles.

Comment: This is certainly true for, say, ideal gases. Can we say anything about the probability distribution of atomic energy for solids, liquids, and non-ideal gases in general?

Comment: There might be some numerical techniques, but I dont know about an analytical approach to your question, besides non-interacting systems.